# Gitlab and Redmine -

Tags: git, centos, redmine, gitlab

I'm looking to get Redmine integration with Gitlab 6.0 working.

**gitlab.yml**:

```
    issues_tracker:
       redmine:

        project_url: "http://issues.myserver.com/projects/:issues_tracker_id"
        issues_url: "http://issues.myserver.com/issues/:id"
        new_issue_url: "http://issues.myserver.com/projects/:issues_tracker_id/issues/new"
```

However, I run into problems and get the following below:

- `We're sorry, but something went wrong` message in the browser
- `production.log` only has the message `Connecting to database specified by database.yml`

If I comment *out* `issues_url` and `new_issue_url`, Gitlab works, but the Gitlab continues to use the "base" issue tracker.

In **gitlab.yml**, `redmine:` has no effect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can only suggest to update to 6.1 as it worked for me flawlessly in that version.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct configuration:

```
  ## External issues trackers
  issues_tracker:
    redmine:
      project_url: "http://domain.com/projects/:issues_tracker_id"
      issues_url: "http://domain.com/issues/:id"
      new_issue_url: "http://domain.com/projects/:issues_tracker_id/issues/new"
```

If you show a copy-paste code part from your config - I can imagine that you misjudge the gaps (not erased once before **redmine:**)

Answer (score 0):

I've met this situation, too. 
I guess you have set something related to issue system before correcting your config file.
Fixing configuration file doesn't fix everything, u need to fix mysql, too.

```
use gitlab;
update projects set issues_tracker="gitlab" where issues_tracker != "gitlab";
```

that should work.